# Is it still possible to file a US federal and/or California personal income tax return for 2020 and 2021?

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Due to various personal reasons related to covid/my health/cross-country move, we were not able to file a US federal and California personal income tax return for 2020 and 2021.

Is it still possible to file a US federal and/or California personal income tax return for 2020 and 2021? I believe I overpaid tax for 2020.

We relocated to India in 2020 and our address is now an Indian address.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

For Federal Taxes:

The tax return for your income earned in 2019 was due in April 2020, has a 3 year deadline, so It must be filed by April 2023.

The tax return for the income earned in 2020 was due in April 2021, has a 3 year deadline, so it must be filed by April 2024.

And so forth.

If you fail to file by the three year deadline, you will not be able to get a refund. If you owe them money, they may already be looking for you, end interest and penalties may be piling up. It is also possible to be in an in-between condition where they have enough information to know you should have filed, and they think you owe them money, but in reality you are due a refund because of things they don't currently have in their records.

For [California](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/help/disagree-or-resolve-an-issue/claim-for-refund.html):

> Statute of limitations
>
> SOL is a time limit imposed by law on the right of taxpayers to file a
> claim for refund.
>
> Generally, you must file your claim for refund by the later of:
>
> - 1 year from the date of overpayment
> - 4 years after the original return due date.
>   If you filed before the due date, you have 4 years from the original return due date to file a claim.
>
>   - If you filed after the extension, the return is late. You have 4 years from the original return due date to file a claim.
>   - If you made payments and never filed a tax return, you have 4 years from the original return due date to file a claim.
> - 4 years after the date of a timely filed return, if filed within the extension period.

Note on Federal deadlines: they changed during the health crisis, Most years the deadline is in April but 2020 and 2021 were different.

Comment: Tax software is also available for prior years, e.g. https://www.taxact.com/products/prior-years "Download Products" tab.

Comment: How do I contact them and let them know that I am working on filing the return?

Comment: Is there a way to find out if there is an outstanding tax bill or demand against me?

Comment: The 2019 tax deadline was actually July 15, 2020. The 2020 tax deadline was actually May 17, 2021.

Comment: @user102008+ but that did NOT (at least not yet) change the refund statute date for those years; see https://www.taxpayeradvocate.irs.gov/news/nta-blog-claims-for-refunds-2019-and-2020-tax-year-trap-for-the-unwary/

Comment: @user674669: you don't need to tell them you are working on it, and they have no provision do do so; just get it filed before the deadline. IRS now has an online account you can create that (among other things) shows status for current year and a few previous, plus at least some notices, but unfortunately it "is not available for taxpayers who have international addresses". I think the online "Get Transcript" has the same limitation, although you could try it; failing that, you could go back to form 4506-T by mail, but their mail handling is backlogged for months so this will be slow. ...

Comment: ... But you could at least [give them your new address](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/irs-procedures/address-changes), so you have a hope of getting any notice(s).